# how to force drupal function to not use DB cache?

Tags: database, drupal, caching

i have a module and i am using **node_load(array('nid' => arg(1)));**
now the problem is that this function keep getting its data for node_load from DB cache.
how can i force this function to not use DB cache?
**Example**
my link is http://mydomain.com/node/344983
now:
    $node=node_load(array('nid'=>arg(1)),null,true);
    echo $node->nid . " -- " arg(1);
**output**
*435632 -- 435632*
which is a randomly node id (available on the system)
and everytime i ctrl+F5 my browser i get new nid!!

Thanks for your help

Comment: if this is in a module, please post your _menu hooks

Comment: function custom_node_menu(){  
    $items = array();
    $items['node'] = array (
        'title' => 'node',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_not_found',
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

Comment: Does `node_load(arg(1))` show similar issues? What does `print arg(1)` output? Is it possible you've got caching on for anonymous users and you're just seeing an earlier output from the page?

Comment: it is written above (435632),,, the problem is that arg(1) getting incorrect value... node_load doesn't have any problem when you use $reset=true
but the problem is with arg api itself!!! i dont know why it gets incorrect values!!

Comment: I very much doubt the issue is with `arg()` itself, or Drupal would cease to function entirely. See my edit regarding caching - try clearing the cache with `devel.module`.

Comment: once i clear the cache either from devel or from database (delete from cache_content;delete from cache_block;) i get correct result for the first time, then it keeps getting this id for next pages (when i work locally of course)

Comment: @Alaa, this seems to be the same question and code you posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547161/4547389

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you calling this? For example, are you using it as part of your template.php file, as part of a page, or as an external module?

Unless you have this wrapped in a function with its own namespace, try naming the variable differently than `$node` -- for example, name it `$my_node`. Depending on the context, the 'node' name is very likely to be accessed and modified by Drupal core and other modules.

If this is happening inside of a function, try the following and let me know what the output is:

```
$test_node_1 = node_load(344983); // Any hard-coded $nid that actually exists
echo $test_node_1->nid;

$test_node_2 = node_load(arg(1)); // Consider using hook_menu loaders instead of arg() in the future, but that's another discussion
echo $test_node_2->nid;

$test_node_3 = menu_get_object(); // Another method that is better than arg()
echo $test_node_3->nid;
```

**Edit:**

Since you're using hook_block, I think I see your problem -- the block itself is being cached, not the node.

Try setting `BLOCK_NO_CACHE` or `BLOCK_CACHE_PER_PAGE` in hook_block, per the documentation at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6

You should also try to avoid arg() whenever possible -- it's a little bit of a security risk, and there are better ways to accomplish just about anything arg() would do in a module environment.

**Edit:***

Some sample code that shows what I'm referring to:

```
function foo_block ($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'list':
        $blocks[0] = array(
          'info' => 'I am a block!',
          'status' => 1,
          'cache' => BLOCK_NO_CACHE // Add this line
        );
        return $block;
      case 'view':
       .....
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that my problem is with arg itself

Comment: it is in hook block..
the result becomes correct if i clear the cache from the database by running the following mysql queries : delete from cache_content;delete from cache_block; .... it gives the result correctly for the first page i browse, then it keeps giving the same nid for next pages

Comment: I am not sure if i got you... but even if i use two different browsers... i got the nid of the first node that i have browsed after clearing my cache...
also if i am logged in as admin, the result appears correct all the time!! this error happens only when i am anonymous user

Comment: Yup - definitely the block cache. Try editing your hook_block implementation with the sample code I provided above -- this disables caching on that block

Comment: Sounds like block caching.  User 1 is excluded from block caching.  Take anschauungs advice and set the cache level to BLOCK_NO_CACHE

Comment: there is one extra issue that you have to do beside setting BLOCK_NO_CACHE which is to run this query
update blocks set cache=-1 where module='YourModuleName';   it is a MUST, if you didnt run it, BLOCK_NO_CACHE will not work as u expect ;)

Answer (score 0):

`node_load` uses `db_query`, which uses `mysql_query` -- so there's no way to easily change the database's cache through that function.

But, `node_load` does use Drupal's `static $nodes` cache -- It's possible that this is your problem instead of the database's cache. You can have `node_load` clear that cache by calling `node_load` with `$reset = TRUE` (`node_load($nid, NULL, TRUE`).

Full documentation is on the node_load manual page at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6

Comment: i have already tried setting $reset to True... but this didnt work :(

Comment: Hrm ... could you describe the specific behavior you're seeing? node_load pulls from potentially a lot of different tables ... could you edit your response to provide some example code, and a sample of what you expected to see?

Comment: I added another answer below -- I believe that the cache is not part of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had luck passing in the node id to node_load not in an array.

node_load(1);

According to [Druapl's api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) this is acceptable and it looks like if you pass in an array as the first variable it's loaded as an array of conditions to match against in the database query.

Comment: The main part of my answer was about how you needed to pass the first variable in as a variable and not an array, which is correct. I'm not sure why I was voted down.

Comment: i dont know who voted you down!! i really appreciate your help.
however, i have voted you up to compromise it :D ;)
best regards
Alaa

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with `arg()`, your issue is that you have caching enabled for anonymous users.

You can switch off caching, or you can exclude your module's menu items from the cache with the [cache exclude module](http://drupal.org/project/cacheexclude).

**edit:** As you've now explained that this is a block, you can use [`BLOCK_NO_CACHE`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) in [`hook_block`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) to exclude your block from the block cache.

Comment: i really appreciate your help,, but this module is to exclude pages...
and here this is a block appears on all pages which are more than 10K pages. so how can i exclude this block (or the module that shows this block) from being cached. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That this is in a block is very relevant information that would've been nice to have in the question itself. There's a reason @Andrew Sledge asked for your `hook_menu` code... Answer updated.